# Which processes are included in the process called cells eating themselves?

Tags: physiology, pathology

I am reading about atrophy and I am thinking to which processes the phrase **cells eating themselves** refer to.

> Cells need something to survive these difficult times. To decrease
>   protein synthesis to survive. If insufficient, cells start
>   to eat themselves. Then, ubiquitine-proteosome pathway and autophagy
>   pathway.

I am not sure if it is only apoptosis.
It can refer here to longer cascade.
I think it can at least refer to autophagy where one cell degrades its components.

**Which processes does the phrase *cells eating themselves* include?**

Comment: The processes are mentioned in the quote you provided: "[ubiquitine-proteosome pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteasome#Ubiquitination_and_targeting) and [autophagy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophagy) pathway". As far as I know, apoptosis _per se_ is not utilized for recycling.

Comment: Please, make that an answer, since it answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

the processes are mentioned in the quote you provided: "[ubiquitine-proteasome pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteasome#Ubiquitination_and_targeting) (note: it's proteAsome) and [autophagy pathway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophagy)". As far as I know, apoptosis *per se* is not utilized for recycling.